# Why is Google able to track me on their sites, even with third-party cookies disabled?

Tags: firefox, cookies

I use Firefox with [third-party cookies disabled](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-third-party-cookies).

I also have a gmail account. Once I’m logged in, I receive a bunch of cookies from XXX.google.com domains. Nothing odd so far.

But when I go to youtube.com, I’m automatically recognized and connected! It seems youtube is able to read XXX.google.com cookies.

How do they do that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only.

Comment: You can just disable Javascript on your browser :).

Comment: Well, how do they programmatically do that? It’s a technical question. @ssbb, that does’t really answer the question.

Comment: Well, that do not. I suppose Youtube is checking for a google OAuth2 authentification everytime somebody connect on. You are connected because gmail provide it.

Comment: _It’s a technical question._ - But it's not a programming question. You're not trying to replicate this behavior in your own code, nor are you trying to write code to get around this. This question is off topic here.

Comment: @ssbb OK, certainly. But it still needs to set a cookie to check I’m the right browser, and XXX.google.com shouldn’t have this permission (I mean, youtube should not be able to read XXX.google.com cookies, but it does read it, oddly).

Comment: @BSMP Right, ok. Can you suggest me on a place I should ask this question instead? Thanks.

Comment: @Gui-Don If You connect on gmail with firefox and youtube on IE, you wont be connect on your profile on youtube. => That's involve Youtube can read google cookie (Well , google & youtube is the same compagny afterall) Or youtube send an ajax Oauth2 Authentification when it detect google cookie (so he can't read it but nevermind, it exist).

Comment: @ssb Of course it can’t read other softwares cookies, each browsers have it’s own cookies database (except, maybe, for flash cookies). But, within the same browser, youtube can (actually, firebug tells me it can) read XXX.google.com cookies. Actually, stack exchange could have the same system, but being logged in stack overflow don’t log me on other stack exchange websites... Only google seems to acheive this.